# Help with Blade mobile network not working

Tags: cyanogenmod, networking, zte-blade

I've been given an Orange San Francisco by my boss to fix for him. At the time he claimed it was bricked but its not as bad as first thought.

His initial problem was that the phone was unable to connect to the mobile network, despite having: a sim inserted, mobile tower in range, APNs configured correctly.

I have got a clean Gen 2 Cyanogen Mod 7.0.3 flashed with no problems. The APN settings are correct according to the Cyanogen APN list but it still doesn't connect to mobile networks.

I myself am a Desire man and so I have little real knowledge of the Blade. If it was a Desire I would try reflashing a radio rom but I'm not sure of the Blade equivalent.

Can anyone suggest what I should do next?

Comment: Under Settings -> Wireless & networks -> Mobile networks -> Network operators does it list anything?

Comment: No it doesn't list anything. Also in About -> Status it says the signal strength is -113 dBm, Service Status is disconnected

Comment: In Dialer app, dial the following: `*#*#4636#*#*` to bring up the "Testing" screen.  Go into Phone Information and scroll down to "Set preferred network type". What does it say on the drop-down?

Comment: It says GSM auto(PRL) . Also has options for WCDMA preferred, GSM only, etc. Not really sure what this means. Btw trying to connect to Orange in the UK

Comment: Orange is a GSM-based carrier, if I'm not mistaken.  "GSM auto (PRL)" should work, but try changing it to "WCDMA Preferred" and see if that works.  You can always change it back.